# Intersect the cells value in column with cells value in row?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am new doing this and desperate need help

I have a group of value in a column and the same group of value in a row, what I need is a VBA code that select the cells where the column and the row intersect. 
Ex.
Col A has values from A2 to A10 and the same values repeat in row 1 from B1:J1
I need a VBA code that select the cell where rowX and ColX intersect.

Thanks

Comment: Are the two areas always a single column and a single row? Will the result ever be more than one cell? Look at using the intersect method. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-intersect-method-excel

Comment: @FcoV, is this right: You have a column of values in A. You have a row of values in 1. These do not intersect at all on the sheet, unless it is at A1, the upper-left corner.  Some value occurs both in column-A and Row-1. Call them by addresses AX and Y1 respectively (X and Y are not literally "X" and "Y", they are labels for placeholders. You want to select the cell at address YX, yes? If so, edit your question accordingly. Will there only be one such cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Highlight_Intersections()
'tested 
    Dim c as Range
    For Each c in Range("B2:J10") 'you supply address
        If Cells(c.Row,1).Value = Cells(2,c.Column).Value Then
            c.Interior.ColorIndex = 6   '(Yellow)
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: I assumed more than one pair of matches would exist. If there is only one then .Select can be used in place of .Interior.ColorIndex = 6. Even if there are many matches you can still do that but only the last match will be selected when it finishes.

Comment: klausnrooster Your code works perfectly, I have changed interior.color by select and it works by selecting every time the row and the column intersects. Thank you very much !!!